# How do I make OpenVPN activate when not in ceratin network

Tags: openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN (interested in client only) and it starts automatically on computer boot. As the connection needs user and password, Ubuntu it even asks for them on computer startup.

I noticed that it imposes a problem when I am in the same network to which I am connecting to. My OpenVPN config has a 'route' command that makes me feel like I am in my network when I am away, but it somehow leads to bad connection when I am in that very network physically.

The precise question is **how do I configure OpenVPN to activate a connection only when** my ip address changes from my home network to some other, or detect that I am away by any other means.

Additional Q#1: Ideally the desired setting should cope with situation when my 4G USB stick assigns me an IP but I still don't have  access to my OpenVPN server, because I have to activate internet on it manually: the OpenVPN client fails to connect and never retries.

Additional Q#2: I'd wish to store the user/password in some safe plsce so that it doesn't ask when automatically connects.

I don't have OpenVPN GUI. If the above settings are too hard to implement I will just install it and activate connections when needed...

/Fedd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` you can solve this problem:

You can configure your network connections to enable a vpn profile if you connect to the network:
[image: gnome-networkmanager vpn at network]

it's in german, but you should get a clue where to search ..

open your network configuration where you want to have vpn enabled automatically and on **general** tab switch on the check mark where it says "connect to vpn automatically when this network is used" and select your pre-defined vpn profile.

Comment: This plugin and a Network Manager is a handy thing. I can control OpenVPN connections from standard interface and tell it to connect to my VPN when I am on a certain WiFi connection. However, what I was looking for was an ability NOT to connect when I am on a certain WiFi or ethernet connection. Is it possible?

Comment: Rephrasing: However, what I was looking for  an ability NOT to connect when I am on a certain WiFi or ethernet connection, but start automatically for all other connections. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure: just set all others to connect except for those that should not. It's a little more effort, but should do the trick.

Comment: sad. What about ethernet connections? How can it use one set of settings at home, another at work and the third in the hotels? I need to invoke VPN only when I use ehternet in hotels, and not when I use ethernet at the office.

Comment: You could set up different Ethernet profiles for each location. :-D